# Load native library inside onSurfaceCreated

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I create I NDK OpenGL ES2 application as inread in a tutorial I load the shared library from java side inside a static block like in the renderer class

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("game");
}
```

but this cause an error `call to opengl es api with no current context` I expected that OpenGL calls from c happens before the surface created and the openGL context become valid, after some researches on google and tries to change the c codes with no success I put the load function inside the `onSurfaceCreated` then the error disappeared.
my question is that a valid procedure specially if the C++ library increased in size and classes? if no what is the correct solution?

Comment: It is strange but not impossible. Could happen if your C++ code starts calling OpenGL on load, e.g. using a constructor of some global variable.

Comment: so is it regular to load the library inside onSurfaceCreated event or should I fix it by another way?

Comment: If you don't have access to the source code of the native lib, and it works when loaded from onSurfaceCreated, and fails otherwise, then let it be this way, in hope that nothing worse will happen on devices that you did not test.

Answer (score 0):

The load function should not reside inside the onSurfaceCreated, the static block is the correct way.

The error is probably because you are starting rendering-related actions too soon - this is why moving the library loading to onSurfaceCreated 'solved' your problem. You need to go over your code and make sure no opengl related code gets executed before the surface is created and rendering starts.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to load the native libraries on app start, preferably on a background thread (therefore static constructor may not be the preferred place to call `loadLibrary()`).

The native code may perform some initialization in `JNI_OnLoad()`, but refrain from starting serious work yet. You should provide JNI functions (Java **native** methods) to start actual work of your C++ code. The benefit of such architecture could be that you have best flexibility to pass the surface or other system resources to the native code.

Consider also providing methods to suspend, restart or stop the C++ processing. Android OS can push your app to background, and then have it in foreground again; the system can kill the app at any time if it runs low on resources, but also a surface can be destroyed and recreated in some situations. Your C++ code should be ready to survive all events.